# MPV on a Zipit Z2, specifically with waf. Building issues

Tags: ffmpeg, mpv

I migrated over here from unix.com.
I have a problem. I'm trying to compile MPV (the multimedia viewer) on a Zipit Z2 (google it). I'm currently chrooting over to it on my desktop computer. And am having problems compiling it.
I've almost got it:

`[208/208] Linking build/mpv`

`` /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.7/../../../libavformat.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_sub_8' ``

`` /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.4.7/../../../libavformat.so: undefined reference to `__sync_fetch_and_add_8' ``

`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`

`` Waf: Leaving directory `/root/mpv-0.29.0/build' ``

`Build failed`

`-> task in 'mpv' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)`

I've googled this, and cannot find any definitive solutions. Hence, what brings me here (from unix.com).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.